# location.href displaying the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am inserting the data into the database and display data on the page without refresh the page.

I tried  `$("#e-empListwrap").load(location.href + "#e-empListwrap");` but it's displaying the whole page on my page.

```
$("form[name='emp']").validate({
  rules: {
    //rules
  },

  submitHandler: function(form) {

    var form = $('form[name="emp"]').get(0);

    var formData = new FormData(form);
    $.ajax({
      url: baseUrl + "/controller/emp_control.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: formData,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,

      success: function(data) {
        $('form[name="emp"]')[0].reset();
        $('#modal-addemp').modal().hide();
        $("#e-empListwrap").load(location.href + "#e-empListwrap");

      },
    }); // AJAX Get Jquery statment

  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="e-empListwrap mt-4" id="e-empListwrap"><ul></ul></div>
 // The below is the script when refersh the page then it will call the ajax and get the the and display on the page.
<script>
fetchEMPsaved_data();
function fetchEMPsaved_data(){
   $.ajax({
        url:'controller/developer_control.php',
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json", 
        data: { action: "fetchEMPsaved_data"},
        success: function(data) {
         $("#e-empListwrap ul").append(data);
        }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: this statement `$("#e-empListwrap").load(location.href + "#e-empListwrap");` is asking JS to load your current webpage into an element. You are returning `data` fromn your ajax function, why not just use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space after the url, between the url and CSS target:

```
 $("#e-empListwrap").load(location.href + " #e-empListwrap");
```

or else jquery handles it as an anchor of the url, not as the element ID. You are loading `url.html#element` but to grep an element/css target, not the whole page, the syntax should be `url.html #elementOrTarget`, with the space in between.

Comment: I am confused, what is this meant to accomplish? OP is still loading the current page into an element on the page... ? Maybe Im misunderstanding something

Comment: He is loading `url.html#element` but to grep an element, not the whole page, the syntax should be `url.html #element`, with the space in between.

Comment: @Daantje, I tried Now I am not getting the whole page but It's clear my all the ajax response

Comment: @Daantje, It's working now, I have changed some code. thank you for the help